# Jquery Cycle - php includes

Tags: php, jquery, include, slider, cycle

I have implemented the Jquery cycle plugin on my page but I can't get one of the parameters to work. Depending on which page I am on I want to start the slide at a different place using `startingSlide: 3`, for example. But it just starts at the beginning.

My question is will the included files affect this, maybe loading in at different times? I'm not sure just clutching at straws really.

The page is at http://www.ukgreenenergy.co.uk/solar-power/

and the initialisation code is here:

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    startingSlide: 3, // zero-based 
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next'
});
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: ooops, its my eyes after this doing my head in - http://www.ukgreenenergy.co.uk/solar-power/ correct link... thanks

Comment: The javascript loads after the page content has loaded, so no, script order shouldn't matter.

Comment: According to the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ukgreenenergy.co.uk%2Fsolar-power%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), you have some unclosed elements and such.

Comment: Brilliant your a gem... it was the markup, can't believe I forgot to validate. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.ukgreenenergy.co.uk/solar-power/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), you have some unclosed elements and such.